# Variable scoping with callbacks- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

In the below code,

```
window.onload = function(){

  function cb(resolve, reject){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open(url);
    http.onload = 1;
    http.onerror = 2;
    //http.send();
  }

  function get(url){
    return new Promise(cb);
  }

};
```

---

Without an anonymous callback, How name `url` can be visible in `cb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not be visible, because it is defined in the function `get`. You can't access it outside of that scope.

One solution I can suggest. Call the `cb` and pass the `url`. This `cb` function will return a function with the actual `cb` logic and can have access to the `url` parameter. Thanks to [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function cb(url){
    return function(resolve, reject) {
       var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
       http.open(url);
       http.onload = 1;
       http.onerror = 2;
       //http.send();
    };    
  }

  function get(url){
    return new Promise(cb(url));
  }

};
```

Comment: But,`new Promise( /* exécuteur */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );`

Comment: Be attentive. I have called `Promise(cb(url))`

Comment: Yes, my bad. Apology. So, Closure is the solution.

Comment: @overexchange Yes. Instead of having a variable which is accessible for two functions, you an use closure